# how to change a css class onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar. I would like to set it up so that when the user clicks the `departments` tab, a css div will slide down and reveal some content. I would like to set this up with 2 pseudo classes. for example

> dropdown.hide, .dropdown.show". dropdown.hide

will be positioned above the header and slide down (with a css transition) it will transform into the new class `(.show)` when the user clicks the departments tab. any ideas on how to pull this off?

Here's my [current code](http://bit.ly/108e3ox). (excuse the glitch edges)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You wanted to use jQuery right for the animation? Or just pure CSS3?

Comment: whatever works the best :)

Comment: Giving you pure CSS3 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of jQuery (for changing class) and CSS3 (for transition). So, you have your CSS well set, and make sure you set these two params:

```
.dropdown.show {transition: all 2s ease;}
.dropdown.hide {transition: all 2s ease;}
```

Now for the jQuery part, we will just be using it to change the class on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav > ul > li > a").toggle(function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        return false;
    }, function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        return false;
    });
});
```

For this, you need to have the `.dropdown`, positioned next to the links. This gets attached to the click event handler. If you want it on `:hover`, you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav > ul > li > a").toggle(function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        return false;
    }, function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you are planning for different sub-menus for each menu item, you need to add them next to the `<a href...>...</a>` tag inside the `nav > ul > li`. A sample code would be:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="dropdown hide">
                    <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

In my opinion, you should not use two classes for the same `div`. A `.hide` and `.show` is not needed. Instead, have just the `.hide` be default and toggle between `.show`!

Comment: excuse me for being so dumb... but this is going to create a full page dropdown right? so when i click it it will be a class like width: 100%; height 300px; for example?

Comment: Yup. That's possible buddy. What's your issue, as there won't be any problem.

Comment: I'm having as issue with your code. does the div have to be placed inside the link i want to trigger the jquery? I need the div outside the header tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Not inside the link, but inside the LI.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Mouseover and Mouseout functions in jQuery. I prefer to use jQuery instead of CSS for this kind of thing...

```
$('nav').find('a').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="divNavBar">Some content</div>');
    $(this).addClass('YourClassName');
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    $('#divNavBar').remove();
    $(this).removeClass('YourClassName');
});
```

Comment: i suggest to take a look at `hover()` if considering this

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question following is the my solution to change the class dynamically.

```
$(".className").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("NewClassName");
});
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.........

Comment: would this allow transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)()

```
$('div').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('show');
```

or [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$('div').slideToggle(1000);
```

Comment: This might give undesired effect in this usecase!

Comment: please explain further @PraveenKumar

Comment: `toggleClass()` say if the user or browser, by mistake sets twice, like `hide` and `show` same time, think of the effects.

Comment: yes if you write other bad code that undermines your good code that is bad. who is doing that?

Comment: Yes, you are right, agree with you. Just for a precaution I said. Anything wrong? :P